# SharePoint 2013 Custom Search page with Taxonomy field

Tags: search-results, taxonomy, csom, taxonomyfieldvalue

We have a SharePoint 2013 on-premise farm and I want to create a search page similar to the one shown below and display search results from a document library(1200+ documents). I found this sample in another O365 SharePoint site but not sure how the Taxonomy field was built...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Kannan, I recommend you to create a web part page and drop Search Box, Search Results & Search Refiners web parts on to it. They will be auto connected to each other as there are single web parts on the page by now. Edit the Refiners web part and click on choose refiners and add the managed metadata properties that you have.

You many not get the look and feel that you are expecting but it will serve your purpose.

Assuming you have already create a Search Service Application, Created Content Source with your web application URL and did a full crawl.

let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I want to build a custom form similar to the screen shot shown above. The solution is to use TaxonomyWebTaggingControl as explained here http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/01/23/using-sharepoint-taxonomywebtaggingcontrol-control-access-and-manipulate-from-client-side/ i'm working on it at the moment...might share the solution if everything works fine... :)

Comment: As per my knowledge, TaxonomyWebTaggingControl will just allow you to pick the terms but not search. After you pick the term do you want to search the content using some custom code? For ex: JSOM, CSOM. In that case you may have to handle rendering the search results also on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the information and source code for The Taxonomy Picker control in this post.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2014/03/13/taxonomy-picker-in-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app.aspx